# How to manage the margins in all devices

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making a layout and it should supposed to be support all devices. I have read developers document and I have come to result that I have to make the different layout for different devices and some tips. SO I started to make for the Mdpi as it is a base line. Now my problem is I want to set my views not in the center but centralized from every side I mean top , left
right bottom and I want to set the spinner one half step down to text field which is at a left of spinner. and I also want that on larger devices this spinner  should have same distance from the text field as it looks in the mdpi .

suppose I have a main layout which is set to the fill parent in width and height and I want another or multiple layout in it which have same distance from left and from right and the views in this layout such as Text field and spinner have some specific distance that should not mess up when we move to larger screen devices. I think You have got my point I can not share my picture as I have not enough  reputations. So I am sharing this link for the layout that I want. [image]
any help ? please send me  the basic xml code thanks .

editing the question and adding my xml code here what I have tried so far:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:padding="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/main_id"
    android:background="@color/bright_foreground_inverse_material_light"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/l_team"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/select_a_team"
            android:id="@+id/tv_team"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/select_a_team"
            android:id="@+id/tv_team_gone"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/sp_team"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_team"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/l_call_date"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/call_date_time"
                android:id="@+id/tv_call_date"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/sp_call_date"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_call_date"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/l_first_name"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/first_name"
                android:id="@+id/tv_first_name"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/sp_first_name"


                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_first_name"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/l_last_name"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/last_name"
                android:id="@+id/tv_last_name"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/sp_last_name"


                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_last_name"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/l_Other_criteria"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/other_critera"
                android:id="@+id/tv_Other_criteria"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/sp_Other_criteria"


                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_Other_criteria"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/l_order_by"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/order_by"
                android:id="@+id/tv_order_by"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/sp_order_by"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_order_by"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/l_results_per_page"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/results_per_page"
                android:id="@+id/tv_results_per_page"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/sp_results_per_page"


                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_results_per_page"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >



        </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Any layout XML code?

Comment: No I have not made any xml layout , I am asking you people to what things should I do to get this result as I wanted

Comment: @Im New can you help me in providing a code . Please ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you meant something like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/Main_Layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:padding="20dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Inner_Layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="10.0"
    android:background="#333"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6.0"
        android:background="#333"
        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4.0">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I hope this will helped you a bit.

Good luck

Comment: No it is not what I want look at the picture what I shared in link. your xml is starting from middle ad spinner is not at the right side of the text view

Comment: It is supposed as an example, you can play around with the layout_weight of both LinearLayout and RelativeLayout. And for the position of the spinner.. You're able to move it around within the RelativeLayout. Even though in designview of Eclipse either Android Studio

Comment: I am adding a code of xml that I have made so far please check is it good?

Comment: Do you want to build something like a ListView? Why don't you use a <ListView> and fill it with an Adapter and a preset xml file with an <EditText> and a <Spinner>? Take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html or http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: If I helped you with this answer, please check and/or upvote. Thank you =)

Comment: No dear I dont want to use the list view